# Read and write to pointer function with memcpy c++

Tags: c++, pointers, memcpy

Hi today I am trying to clean up my code and I'm a little new on pointers and memcpy.
What I am trying to do is something where I can do this.

pos()->x = 500;
or even printf(pos->x)

CODE SO FAR - READ ONLY

```
struct vec3
{
    float x, y, z;
};

vec3 client::pos()
{
    vec3 vPos;
    memcpy(&vPos, &(*(float *)(state() + 0x1C)), sizeof(vec3));
    return vPos;
}
```

The above code will correctly return Z,Y and Z cords but obviously its not a pointer so cannot set one.

I really have not a clue how I could reverse the use off my above method well not reverse but rather use it both ways then defining two methods for this.

Below is an example of how I am currently setting pos

```
void client::setPos(float x, float y, float z)
{
    vec3 vPos = {
        x==NULL?pos().x:x,
        y==NULL?pos().y:y,
        z==NULL?pos().z:z
    };
    memcpy(&(*(float *)(state() + cordX)), &vPos, sizeof(vec3));
}
```

How can I "bind" those two methods into one by making my first one a pointer?

Comment: Why don't you want to keep your code? (the compiler might play pointer tricks if permitted by the ABI)

Comment: I'm unsure what you mean by "keep your code" i mean I don't want to add another method just to write it.

Comment: Why do you check x, y and z for NULL in the setPos function? These are not pointers...

Comment: Because the default params are equal to NULL. If that cord isn't specified then set with current cord. And no kidding they're not pointed the entire point of this post is to make an all in one pointer.

Comment: AFAIK NULL is defined as (void*)(0), so you're effectively setting these to 0.f by implicit cast - is that really what you intended there?

Comment: You should join us in 2014 and go do some research on what conditional statements are.

Comment: x==NULL?pos().x:x = if(x==NULL)pos().x ELSE x

Comment: I was not referring to the ternary statement but to you mentioning default parameters. NULL is not a value of float to represent "undefined", but is exactly 0.f. You're code as far as I can see makes it impossible to set (x y z) = (0.f 0.f 0.f) and my question was if you wanted/tested this behaviour. IF you want to check floats for the value 0, it is mostly better to use absf(x) < std::numeric_limits<float>::epsilon().

Comment: Ahh I understand now, but as far as I am aware its safe; no warnings thrown. #define NULL 0. And I cannot use anything from standard as this is an xbox one app.

Comment: `state() + 0x1C` looks fishy to me. Do you really need it like this? What does the state look like?

Comment: This is my state() http://i.imgur.com/PnFvKpG.png it just returns an address to clients state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
vec3* client::pos()
{
    return (vec3*)(state() + 0x1C);
}
```

This way, pos() should return a vec3 pointer pointing to the internally stored data. Callers of pos() can then directly modify that data (if that's really what you want).

Note that you're giving out pointers to internal memory, you have to somehow deal with memory lifetime issues (eg. what happens if state() points to different memory later while somebody still uses the return value of pos()?).

Comment: state() is always the current players state :) there should be no issues, going to give this a try. looks simple and promising. thanks!

Comment: client is a class array, now just to double check I should be safe right? do you recommend something? I monitor players leave and do variable resets. Are you saying I need to kill that pointer somehow when client leaves? and it works great!

Comment: As long as you just use it like "someclient.pos()->x = 500" you should be fine. But if you do stuff like "vec3* thePos = someclient->pos(); delete someclient;", thePos will point to invalid memory. So you have to be very careful when using pos() (I don't know of any way to let the compiler catch such errors). In my experience this makes the entire code more difficult to maintain. But to be honest, with those "state() + 0x1C" statements your code already appears to be in pretty bad shape, so the pos() stuff won't make it much worse :-D

Comment: Ha, thanks. Have yet to face any issues yet. Very very stable and responsive. So you mean if I define a new pointer as pos? that wont be happening :) thats why I needed this in the first place. Just going to be for quick reading and writing / calculations. I will do some testing and see how things go.

Comment: Heres two examples of your magic in use http://i.imgur.com/eiTrQ5r.png // http://i.imgur.com/I0QeXM5.png for simeple use that that sohuldnt be any issues right?

Comment: Hey while you're at it I am guessing you know a little bit about vec3. I've been trying to make a distance calc for hours now. Any advice would be wonderful! I just want it to return integers like 1-100 of how close pos1 is to pos2

Comment: The examples in your code seem to be ok, yes. Regarding the distance calculation, have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance . I don't have a C++ implementation at hand, but you should be able to implement that yourself, or find an existing library that implements this.

Comment: Replaced everything with memcpy rather then ugly vec3 = *pointer() plus probably safer and cleaner. Also "return sqrt((v1.x - v2.x) * (v1.x - v2.x) + (v1.y - v2.y) * (v1.y - v2.y) + (v1.z - v2.z) * (v1.z - v2.z));" does the job! thank you for that research